# System.Threading.Timer ... Time of next fire?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I have a question about the timer. Does interval time count time of callback executions? I mean for example - I have a timer set to fire every 15 seconds and it executes a callback function that lasts approximately 3 seconds in time. When the next time the timer will fire? In 18 seconds (after callback completes) or after 15 seconds (without waiting for callback)???
Thanks in advance

Comment: The timer has nothing to do with its callback. It will fire at 15 secs

Comment: so the callback will be executed in another thread?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/dont-be-afraid-to-use-the-science/

Comment: Yes, a threadpool thread. It's in the docs `The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.`

Answer (score 3):

It will fire every 15 seconds regardless of the callback execution time. If you want it to include the callback execution time, you can suspend and restart the timer in the callback as follows;

At the start:

`someTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)`

.. and at the end, change it back with the same method:

`someTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))`

Comment: You don't need to change the timer at the start, just never specify a period so the timer fires only once. This way the `Change` call at the callback's end will reset the timer

Answer (score 1):

It will fire every 15 secs. Any delays by the callback do not affect the timer. The callback executes on a separate ThreadPool thread. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system.

If you want to take the processing time into account, you would have to manage the timer yourself - start a single-fire timer and reset it from inside the callback, eg:

```
TimerCallback tcb = MyCallBack;
//Start the timer once after 15 secs
_timer=new Timer(tcb,null,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),TimeSpan.Infinite);

...
void MyCallBack(Object stateInfo)
{
   ....
   //Reset the timer
   _timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),TimeSpan.Infinite);
}
```

An easier and cleaner way is to use `async/await` to wait X seconds after each asynchronous execution. For example, the following code will execute a method 15 secs after its last execution:

```
while(...)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    var response=await Task.Run(()=>someMethod());
    ...
}
```

or, if you want to execute code that is already asynchronous

```
while(...)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    await myHttpClient.GetStringAsync(someURL);
}
```

Under the hood, `Task.Delay` creates a single-fire timer and completes when the timer finishes. It's almost the same thing you would do manually.